# Plot bubbles on world map using geopandas and pandas in python (most simple solution)

Tags: pandas, dictionary, plot, geopandas

how can I plot the dataframe-info below onto the geopandas map? Bubble size should be dependant on case-numbers!

```
import geopandas
import geoplot
import pandas


d = {"Germany": 5, "United Kingdom" : 3, "Finland" : 1, "United States of America" : 4}
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index')
df.columns = ["Cases"]

def WorldCaseMap():
    world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
    ex = geoplot.polyplot(world)


WorldCaseMap()
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a second df containing centroid geometry and plot it over the first one. Working example below.

```
import geopandas as gpd
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

centroids = world.copy()
centroids.geometry = world.centroid
centroids['size'] = centroids['pop_est'] / 1000000  # to get reasonable plotable number

ax = world.plot(facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
centroids.plot(markersize='size', ax=ax)
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure `geopandas` gives you a bubble-map that easily. Their best example is a choropleth:

```py
gpd_per_person = world['gdp_md_est'] / world['pop_est']
scheme = mapclassify.Quantiles(gpd_per_person, k=5)

# Note: this code sample requires geoplot>=0.4.0.
geoplot.choropleth(
    world, hue=gpd_per_person, scheme=scheme,
    cmap='Greens', figsize=(8, 4)
)
```

[Source](https://geopandas.org/gallery/plotting_with_geoplot.html?highlight=polyplot)

I found another example of bubble-maps using `geopandas` here: https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/gallery/plot_usa_city_elevations.html however I prefer the look of the plotly example. (See below).

Otherwise have a look at plotly's examples they have a bubble map: https://plot.ly/python/bubble-maps/